# Mirror 3D node location based on another node in Godot 3.2

Tags: godot

I want to copy the location of a node without the rotation. I could set it as the child, but there is no way to ignore the rotation.

In 2D, I could use the position of one node to set the [position of another](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html#class-node2d-property-position). Unfortunately I haven't found the 3D alternative. In [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/897ddx/how_to_find_3d_position/) there is a description but it uses legacy Godot code.

There doesn't seem to be a 3D position function for the Spatial node.

The following non-functional code shows what I'm trying to do.

```
extends Spatial

var target

func _ready():
    target = get_node("Target")

func _process(delta):
    self.transform.position = target.transform.position
```

Comment: Check out the [RemoteTransform](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_remotetransform.html) node, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found out how to do it. You can copy the global_transform origin to set it to the same location.

```
extends Spatial

var target

func _ready():
    target = get_node("../Player/Target")

func _process(delta):
    self.global_transform.origin = target.global_transform.origin
```